# Two(≥2) signal handlers execution order when one is interrupted by another?

Tags: signals

Suppose in `main` I register 2 signal handlers for `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUR2`, let's say `sig_ur1` and `sig_ur2`. What's gonna happen when signal `SIGUR2` arrives when `sig_ur1` is running?

`sig_ur1` running ----> signal `SIGUR2` arrives  ----> :

1. `sig_ur1` keeps  running -> `sig_ur1` finishes -> `sig_ur2` starts to run -> `sig_ur2` finishes -> return to `main`
2. `sig_ur2` starts to run -> `sig_ur2` finishes -> return to `main`
3. `sig_ur2` starts to run -> `sig_ur2` finishes -> `sig_ur1` restores(variables keep the same value when `sig_ur1` left) -> `sig_ur1` finishes -> return to `main`
4. `sig_ur2` starts to run -> `sig_ur2` finishes -> `sig_ur1` restarts(all variables are initialized again) -> `sig_ur1` finishes -> return to `main`

Which option is the correct one? Or neither is correct? I did not find any articles/posts talking about this, so providing any related material/links would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default scenario 3 is what happens. However you may make provision for blocking SIGUSR2 whenever running SIGUSR1’s handler, and thus you’d have scenario 1 occurring. When you install a signal’s handler you can specify which signals you want to block while running that signal’s handler.

As reference I would recommend you reading your operating system’s man-pages regarding signals. For instance on Linux you might start from `man 7 signal` and from there the SEE ALSO man-pages.

However you can easily check the behavior by yourself: just make a handler for SIGUSR1 that goes to a long sleep(3) (in Linux better nanosleep(2) because sleep(3) might be implemented through SIGALRM), then send first SIGUSR1 and then SIGUSR2.